# angular nested data object computed value binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, computed-values

I have a table of data, a list of staff and their salaries for each month of the year where there is a total for each month across all staff which is calculated dynamically (sum of salaries that fall in that month).

I am trying to get it so that when I change one of the staff salaries for a particular month the calculated total for that month re-evaluates and therefore angular will update the ui but as this total property is computed I can't see a way to 'mark it as dirty' so angular knows to re-evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario sounds like it could use a custom filter.

Something close to:

**custom filter**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('mySumFilter', function() {
  return function(items, param1, param2) {
    return //perform sum items object in case of necessary use params to narrow your operation
  };
});
```

and in your **html**

```
 <div> {{ salaryArray |mySumFilter:'salary': 2"}} </div>
```

Of course you could extend it and perform the actions that are more suited to your app needs.